# Python VS Code producing excess output

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to run my python debugger in vscode, it runs but produces a massive amount of output and I'm not sure why.
This simple program:

```
print('hello world!')
```

Produces this output in the terminal:

```
& 'C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\python.exe' 'c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '56764' '--' 'test' 
Using GEVENT_SUPPORT: False
pydevd __file__: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py
pydevd: Use libraries filter: False

IDE_PROJECT_ROOTS []

Collecting default library roots.
LIBRARY_ROOTS ['C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2\\Lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages']

Connecting to 127.0.0.1:56763
Connected.
Process PydevdAuthorizeRequest: {
    "arguments": {},
    "command": "pydevdAuthorize",
    "seq": 1,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 1, "success": true, "command": "pydevdAuthorize", "body": {"clientAccessToken": "01613d0f058317954171a32f34b5822ea3741cf3eec19ff1469796e32afa3f03"}, "seq": 2, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process PydevdSystemInfoRequest: {
    "arguments": {},
    "command": "pydevdSystemInfo",
    "seq": 2,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 2, "success": true, "command": "pydevdSystemInfo", "body": {"python": {"version": "3.8.5final0", "implementation": {"name": "cpython", "version": "3.8.5final0", "description": "CPython"}}, "platform": {"name": "win32"}, "process": {"pid": 221700, "ppid": 221604, "executable": "C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2\\python.exe", "bitness": 64}, "pydevd": {"usingCython": false, "usingFrameEval": false}}, "seq": 4, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process EvaluateRequest: {
    "arguments": {
        "expression": "\nif 'debugpy' not in sys.modules:\n    sys.path.insert(0, 'c:\\\\Users\\\\user\\\\.vscode\\\\extensions\\\\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\\\\pythonFiles\\\\lib\\\\python')\n    try:\n        import debugpy\n    finally:\n        del sys.path[0]\n",
        "format": {}
    },
    "command": "evaluate",
    "seq": 3,
    "type": "request"
}

processing internal command: InternalThreadCommands(<function internal_evaluate_expression_json at 0x00000197CD0B0160>, (<_pydevd_bundle._debug_adapter.pydevd_schema.EvaluateRequest object at 0x00000197CD2630A0>, '*'), {})
sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 3, "success": true, "command": "evaluate", "body": {"result": "", "variablesReference": 0, "presentationHint": {}}, "seq": 6, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process PydevdAuthorizeRequest: {
    "arguments": {},
    "command": "pydevdAuthorize",
    "seq": 4,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 4, "success": true, "command": "pydevdAuthorize", "body": {"clientAccessToken": "01613d0f058317954171a32f34b5822ea3741cf3eec19ff1469796e32afa3f03"}, "seq": 8, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process InitializeRequest: {
    "arguments": {
        "adapterID": "python",
        "clientID": "vscode",
        "clientName": "Visual Studio Code",
        "columnsStartAt1": true,
        "linesStartAt1": true,
        "locale": "en-us",
        "pathFormat": "path",
        "supportsProgressReporting": true,
        "supportsRunInTerminalRequest": true,
        "supportsVariablePaging": true,
        "supportsVariableType": true
    },
    "command": "initialize",
    "seq": 5,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 5, "success": true, "command": "initialize", "seq": 10, "body": {"supportsConfigurationDoneRequest": true, "supportsFunctionBreakpoints": false, "supportsConditionalBreakpoints": true, "supportsHitConditionalBreakpoints": true, "supportsEvaluateForHovers": true, "exceptionBreakpointFilters": [{"filter": "raised", "label": "Raised Exceptions", "default": false}, {"filter": "uncaught", "label": "Uncaught Exceptions", "default": true}, {"filter": "userUnhandled", "label": "User Uncaught Exceptions", "default": false}], "supportsStepBack": false, "supportsSetVariable": true, "supportsRestartFrame": false, "supportsGotoTargetsRequest": true, "supportsStepInTargetsRequest": false, "supportsCompletionsRequest": true, "completionTriggerCharacters": [], "supportsModulesRequest": true, "additionalModuleColumns": [], "supportedChecksumAlgorithms": [], "supportsRestartRequest": false, "supportsExceptionOptions": true, "supportsValueFormattingOptions": true, "supportsExceptionInfoRequest": true, "supportTerminateDebuggee": true, "supportsDelayedStackTraceLoading": true, "supportsLoadedSourcesRequest": false, "supportsLogPoints": true, "supportsTerminateThreadsRequest": false, "supportsSetExpression": true, "supportsTerminateRequest": true, "supportsDataBreakpoints": false, "supportsReadMemoryRequest": false, "supportsDisassembleRequest": false, "supportsDebuggerProperties": true, "pydevd": {"processId": 221700}}, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process LaunchRequest: {
    "arguments": {
        "__sessionId": "1df1314f-0b89-442d-bb61-c50d51504139",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "cwd": "c:\\code\\python\\python_zmq",
        "debugOptions": [
            "ShowReturnValue",
            "FixFilePathCase"
        ],
        "env": {
            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "UTF-8",
            "PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "1"
        },
        "envFile": "c:\\code\\python\\python_zmq/.env",
        "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
        "justMyCode": true,
        "name": "hello world",
        "processName": "test",
        "program": "test",
        "pythonArgs": [],
        "pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\user\\Anaconda3\\envs\\trader2\\python.exe",
        "request": "launch",
        "showReturnValue": true,
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "type": "python",
        "workspaceFolder": "c:\\code\\python\\python_zmq"
    },
    "command": "launch",
    "seq": 6,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->    CMD_PROCESS_EVENT {"type": "event", "event": "process", "body": {"name": "test", "systemProcessId": 221700, "isLocalProcess": true, "startMethod": "launch"}, "seq": 12, "pydevd_cmd_id": 204}

pydevd: Use libraries filter: True

Show return values: True
sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 6, "success": true, "command": "launch", "seq": 14, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process SetDebuggerPropertyRequest: {
    "arguments": {
        "ideOS": "WINDOWS",
        "multiThreadsSingleNotification": true,
        "skipPrintBreakpointException": [
            "NameError"
        ],
        "skipSuspendOnBreakpointException": [
            "BaseException"
        ]
    },
    "command": "setDebuggerProperty",
    "seq": 7,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 7, "success": true, "command": "setDebuggerProperty", "seq": 16, "body": {}, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}        

Process SetExceptionBreakpointsRequest: {
    "arguments": {
        "filters": [
            "uncaught"
        ]
    },
    "command": "setExceptionBreakpoints",
    "seq": 8,
    "type": "request"
}

Exceptions to hook on terminate: {'BaseException': <_pydevd_bundle.pydevd_breakpoints.ExceptionBreakpoint object at 0x00000197CD25A850>}.
sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 8, "success": true, "command": "setExceptionBreakpoints", "seq": 18, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

Process ConfigurationDoneRequest: {
    "arguments": {},
    "command": "configurationDone",
    "seq": 9,
    "type": "request"
}

sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 9, "success": true, "command": "configurationDone", "seq": 20, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

sending cmd -->    CMD_THREAD_CREATE {"type": "event", "event": "thread", "body": {"reason": "started", "threadId": 1}, "seq": 22, "pydevd_cmd_id": 103}

File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\ntpath.py
Process ThreadsRequest: {
    "command": "threads",
    "seq": 10,
    "type": "request"
}

File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\genericpath.py
sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 10, "success": true, "command": "threads", "body": {"threads": [{"id": 1, "name": "MainThread"}]}, "seq": 24, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py
Successfully Loaded helper lib to set tracing to all threads.
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py - set_tracing_for_untraced_contexts
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py - _locked_settrace
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py - settrace
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py - _settrace
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py - connect
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py - debug
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\__init__.py - connect
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\common\compat.py - kwonly_f
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py - start_debugging
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py - run_file
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py - main
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py - <module>
Set tracing of frame: C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py - _run_code
Set tracing of frame: C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py - _run_module_as_main
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py - settrace
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py - _settrace
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py - connect
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\api.py - debug
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\__init__.py - connect
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\common\compat.py - kwonly_f
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py - start_debugging
Process ThreadsRequest: {
    "command": "threads",
    "seq": 11,
    "type": "request"
}

SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py - run_file
sending cmd -->           CMD_RETURN {"type": "response", "request_seq": 11, "success": true, "command": "threads", "body": {"threads": [{"id": 1, "name": "MainThread"}]}, "seq": 26, "pydevd_cmd_id": 502}

SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py - main
SKIP set tracing of frame: c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py - <module>
File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\string.py
File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\site.py
File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\sysconfig.py
File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py
File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\pkgutil.py
File not traced (not in project - force_check_project_scope): c:\users\user\anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\os.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 430, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy/..\debugpy\server\cli.py", line 267, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name=compat.force_str("__main__"))
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py", line 264, in run_path
    code, fname = _get_code_from_file(run_name, path_name)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\trader2\lib\runpy.py", line 234, in _get_code_from_file
    with io.open_code(decoded_path) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\code\\python\\python_zmq\\test'
sending cmd -->      CMD_THREAD_KILL {"type": "event", "event": "thread", "body": {"reason": "exited", "threadId": 1}, "seq": 28, "pydevd_cmd_id": 104}

PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads (called from: File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 1581, in process_internal_commands)
No threads alive, finishing debug session
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads (first call)
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads no commands being processed.
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads killing thread: <_TimeoutThread(Thread-4, started daemon 222216)>
Thread-4 received kill signal
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads (called from: File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\pydevd.py", line 238, in _on_run)
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads killing thread: <ReaderThread(pydevd.Reader, started daemon 211432)>
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads (already disposed - wait)
pydevd.Reader received kill signal
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads waiting for pydb daemon threads to finish
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads killing thread: <PyDBCommandThread(pydevd.CommandThread, started daemon 222236)>
pydevd.CommandThread received kill signal
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads killing thread: <WriterThread(pydevd.Writer, started daemon 221352)>
sending cmd -->             CMD_EXIT {"type": "event", "event": "terminated", "seq": 30, "body": {}, "pydevd_cmd_id": 129}

pydevd.Writer received kill signal
WriterThread: CMD_EXIT received
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads killing thread: <CheckAliveThread(pydevd.CheckAliveThread, started 222248)>
ReaderThread: empty contents received (len(line) == 0).
WriterThread: exit
pydevd.CheckAliveThread received kill signal
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads (called from: File "c:\Users\user\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.9.112786\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_comm.py", line 305, in _terminate_on_socket_close)
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads (already disposed - wait)
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads: finished
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads: finished
ReaderThread: exit
The following pydb threads may not have finished correctly: pydevd.CommandThread
PyDB.dispose_and_kill_all_pydevd_threads: finished
pydevd.stoptrace()
```

Which is ridiculous as I can't even find the print output in that dump. I tried uninstalling vscode and deleting settings but that didn't work.

```
conda 4.8.5
Python 3.7.9
Windows 10 - Build 20221
```

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Looks like a VS code extension 'debugpy' might be being run when you run your program also. Can you see if you have that extension and try to remove it? Also see if you have a launch.json file with your environment setup

Comment: you must have enabled some debug trace in the settings file. Try it with global and workspace (.vscode) `settings.json` files empty or only the selected python interpreter

Comment: @JohnS only extension I have installed is 'ms-python.python'

Comment: @rioV8 Both local and global settings.json files are empty same result.

Comment: have a look at the `OUTPUT - Python` Panel and see for which experiment your a member at the top of the log. According to https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/274#issuecomment-637745823 you can optOutFrom experiments

Comment: @rioV8 I'm not opted out of any.

Comment: I'm not getting this issue when debugging on WSL Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Maybe you need to optOutFrom an experiment